# Running buffer algorithm from processing on each feature from one layer in pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, qgis-processing

In a standalone outside script for QGIS 2.18, i have a layer which contain multiple features to bufferize :

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(out_dir + "selected_shape.shp", "blabla", "ogr")
```

I try to run processing for each features

```
from qgis.core import *
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
import processing

buff_res = processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", vlayer, 0.2, 99, False, None,)

get_output= processing.getObject(buff_res['OUTPUT'])

for f in get_output.getFeatures():
    print f.attributes()
```

The `qgis:fixeddistancebuffer` compute the buffer only on the first feature from my layer. How can i compute the buffer on each feature on this vlayer ?

Comment: Do you need to apply different buffers for each feature?

Comment: Nop, same buffer for each feature :)

Answer (score 2):

If I directly use your code to a sample polygonal layer:

[image]

it seems to works:

[image]

The **Fixed distance buffer** algorithm from **Processing** iterates, by default, over each feature of your layer. There is something more that I don't understand?

Comment: Using standalone script or directly into QGIS ? Because using Qgis yes, it works, but not with the python script ...

Comment: What do you intend with "python script"? A script runned inside or outside QGIS? I tested your code creating a new script under the `Tools` group in the `Script` algorithms block of the `Processing Toolbox`...

Comment: Yes, a standalone outside QGIS script